# Flyway unable to set schema in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, flyway

my problem is that I cannot perform a migration from flyway java spring, even though the migration files are detected, and the same migration files work from cmd.

I have already tried to set all possibly useful parameters I found on the internet to configure the schema, but it still sticks at "PUBLIC"

First of all the problem is as below: (logs from Java spring)

```
"2019-07-01 15:06:04.296  INFO 296 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
2019-07-01 15:06:04.297  INFO 296 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 - Create person table
2019-07-01 15:06:04.324  INFO 296 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 2 - Add people
2019-07-01 15:06:04.339  INFO 296 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 3 - Add people2
2019-07-01 15:06:04.356  INFO 296 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 3 migrations to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.094s)"
```

The table is called **public**, and I also cannot see it from mysql workbench.

But if I do it from command line with flyway migrate, it alters the schema called **td**, which is my intention:

```
"Migrating schema `td` to version 1 - Create person table
Migrating schema `td` to version 2 - Add people
Successfully applied 2 migrations to schema `td` (execution time 00:00.207s)"
```

The flyway config for Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
    flyway.migrate();
    SpringApplication.run(TimeReportApplication.class, args);
}
```

application.properties:

```
flyway.user=root
flyway.password=root
flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/td
flyway.schemas=TD
```

The working flyway config for command line:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/td
flyway.user=root
flyway.password=root
```

Do you have any suggestions what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a day of trying, I found a solution:

1. You have to add "Datasource" to your initialization file. This will be autoconfigured by Spring from your application.properties file, which you have to place in src/main/resources:

   public class TimeReportApplication {

   ```
   @Autowired
   static DataSource dataSource;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       PrintLog.print("Server started");
       System.out.println("Server started");
       Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
       flyway.clean();
       flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
       flyway.setSqlMigrationPrefix("V");
       flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
       flyway.migrate();
       SpringApplication.run(TimeReportApplication.class, args);
   }
   ```

   }
2. In your application.properties file write before each parameter "spring", e.g.:
   spring.flyway.user=root

Comment: btw just setting things up with `spring` prefix before `flyway` properties helped me without any additional steps